# French/Portuguese Numero character not rendered in XAML properly

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to display the french and Portuguese Numero character (`n.º`) in XAML page.

But the underscore under the symbol o is missing while rendering into the XAML page.

Code: `<TextBlock FontSize="20"  Foreground="Black" Text="Bay n.º"/>`

Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Eq9.png

please anyone help me to sort this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="Black">
    <Run Text="Bay n."></Run>
    <Run Text="º" TextDecorations="Underline"></Run>
</TextBlock>
```

You need to underline the character that you want to display, in XAML there are certain combinations that you can only do them with the Run or by code.

Or you can try something like this:

```
<TextBlock FontSize="20"  Foreground="Black" Text="Bay n.&#x2116;"/>
```

However, I strongly suggest the first option.

More examples:
https://raviranjankr.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/how-to-format-texts-of-textblock-using-xaml-in-windows-phone/

In this example they do it with C# code, you can try it as a possible alternative.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/915740e9-a693-40b9-96a4-07d2784d3b53/textblock-underline-in-winrt?forum=winappswithcsharp